# Find pairs in sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, schema

I want to write a query that will show pairs of years in which there was a Dwayne Johnson movie. For example, 2003 and 2004, in 2004 and 2005, in 2005 and 2006, and so on...

```
Example Demo:
Year, Year
2001, 2002
2003, 2004
2005, 2006
```

Here is my schema:

```
Actor:
    aid INT PRIMARY KEY
    first VARCHAR
    last VARCHAR

Movie:
    mid INT PRIMARY KEY
    title VARCHAR
    year INT

Role:
    aid INT REFERENCES Actor(aid)
    mid INT REFERENCES Movie(mid)
```

Here is what I have currently:

```
select distinct m1.year, m2.year from movie m1, movie m2
JOIN role r ON m1.mid = r.mid JOIN actor a ON r.aid = a.aid
where a.first='Dwayne' AND a.last='Johnson'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join the `movie` and `role` tables twice to get all consecutive pairs of years.

```
select m1.year, m2.year
from movie m1
join role r1 on r1.mid = m1.id
join actor a on r.aid = a.aid
join role r2 on r2.aid = a.aid
join movie m2 on r2.mid = m2.id
where m1.year + 1 = m2.year
and a.first='Dwayne' and a.last='Johnson'
```

Comment: This is close, I had done something like this before... only thing is that I would need a check on it to make sure that the years are right after each other so I don't want 1991 and 1995 showing up but I want 1991 and 1992 or 1993 and 1994 showing up... Please check my example in the question. This is the part that I am confused about.

Comment: Ah, I subtracted m2.year from m1.year and checked if it was equal to 1 in my WHERE clause. It would be helpful for others to look over.